# cufon not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cufon

Can anyone tell me why Cufon isnt working on the following site: http://www.rnmtest.co.uk/aim/

Looks right to me but it just isn't working.

Comment: looks fine to me and i think it's working.

Comment: are you sure? what browser r u using?

Comment: what is it you are expecting and what is it that makes it not working?

Comment: It should replace the page titles which are h2's with a jazzier font. Its not doing that on mine

Comment: try to disable all jquery plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@geoffs3310: You realise you've commented the `Cufon` code out, right?

```
<!--<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/L_VAG_Rounded_Light_500-B_VAG_Rounded_Bold_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1, h2');
</script>-->
```

**Update**

@geoffs3310: I think your font is broken... I just downloaded another one from http://www.cufonfonts.com/ to test and using your above code (uncommented), with @kjy112's additional snippet, got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

add `<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>` to the bottom of your page.

List of things to look for:

- A transitional doctype will break
  line-height, use a strict or HTML5
  doctype.
- Avoid whitespace (or anything else
  for that matter) before the doctype.
  This has been known to affect
  printing in IE.
- UTF-8 is the only supported character
  set. Use others at your own risk.
  Characters may go missing.

As for IE9, upgrade to [Cufon 1.09i](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

Comment: I placed only Cufon.replace('#content h2, .menu li a');  . Then I added Cufon.now(); before above line.Worked fine.Thanks a lot!